# Highlight empty space between words in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new in jQuery so i have 2 questions.

1-How can I highlight empty space between words in this function?

2-How can I highlight just `<abbr class="word p1">` tag?

**HTML Code:**

```
<span id="4">
<abbr class="word p1" >&#xfb62;</abbr>
<abbr class="word p1" >&#xfb63;</abbr>
<abbr class="word p1" >&#xfb64;</abbr>
<abbr class="word p1" >&#xfb65;</abbr>
<abbr class="end p1" >&#xfb66;</abbr>
</span >
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
$(function(){
    var time = 5;
    $("abbr", "#4").each(function(i,e) {
        $(e).delay(i*((time*1000)/$("abbr", "#4").length)).animate({'background-color': '#0f0'}, 500);
    });
});​
```

**Css Code:**

```
span
{
    text-align:justify;
    float:right;
}

    @font-face {
        font-family: 'p1';
        src: url('http://c216429.r29.cf1.rackcdn.com/p1.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-           opentype'),
             url('http://c216429.r29.cf1.rackcdn.com/p1.woff')       format('woff'),
             url('http://c216429.r29.cf1.rackcdn.com/p1.ttf')        format('truetype'),
             url('http://c216429.r29.cf1.rackcdn.com/p1.svg#p1')    format('svg');
    }

    .p1 {
        font-family: 'p1';
    }​
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/eTyaV/

Comment: If you put the spaces inside the <abbr> does that not achieve what your after? http://jsfiddle.net/eTyaV/2/

Comment: thank's @Jeemusu.,and what about second question,any idea?

Comment: FYI, the first character of an ID must be a letter. You can't have IDs that are just numbers.

Comment: @Barmar - That is _so_ 2005. Numeric IDs are fine in html5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment above, just include the spaces within the  tags to solve your space highlighting issue.

```
<span id="4">
    <abbr class="word p1" >&#xfb62; </abbr>
    <abbr class="word p1" >&#xfb63; </abbr>
    <abbr class="word p1" >&#xfb64; </abbr>
    <abbr class="word p1" >&#xfb65; </abbr>
    <abbr class="end p1" >&#xfb66;</abbr>
</span >
```

As for point 2, you could check to see if the element has a class of "word p1" in your each loop, by using a condition like `if($(e).hasClass('word')) {}`.

```
$(function(){
    var time = 5;

    $("abbr").each(function(i,e) {

        if($(e).hasClass('word')) {  
            $(e).delay(i*((time*1000)/$("abbr").length)).animate({'background-color': '#0f0'}, 500);
        }
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eTyaV/7/

Answer (score 1):

put the spaces inside the `<abbr>`

.this will solw empty space

```
<span id="4">
    <abbr class="word p1" >&#xfb62; </abbr>
    <abbr class="word p1" >&#xfb63; </abbr>
    <abbr class="word p1" >&#xfb64; </abbr>
    <abbr class="word p1" >&#xfb65; </abbr>
    <abbr class="end p1" >&#xfb66;</abbr>
</span >
```

Answer (score 0):

To highlight only `<abbr>` elements with class `word p1` just write

```
$('abbr.word.p1').css({background:'0f0'});
```